# How to get my twitter feed next to my video on the same line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my live twitter feed to be right next to my youtube video and I want them to be on the same line but don't know what code to implement so that this works.

Also I want to use another font family to the one I have used in my code, where can I find them and how do I implement it into my code?

Below I have provided the html, css and js for my webpage, if you can please fix the errors thanks.

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Muhammed's Webpage</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
  <script src="homepage.js"></script>

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700|Arya:400,700|Nunito:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body><img src="https://www.facebookbrand.com/img/fb-art.jpg" height=85px>

  <div id="page">

    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#BasicInfo"> BASIC INFORMATION </a></li>
        <li><a href="#Curriculum Vitae"> CURRICULUM VITAE </a></li>
        <li><a href="#Portfolio"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
        <li><a href="#Report"> REPORT </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="yt">
      <iframe height="400" width="700" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nKIu9yen5nc">
      </iframe>
    </div>

  <div id = "twitter">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/applenws" data-widget-id="674678491141570560">Tweets by @applenws</a>
  </div>

    <div class="content" id="Basic Information">
      <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Basic Information</u> </h3>
      <p>In this section i will have some information about myself.
        <br> For my finished website i'd like to make it responsive, so that it alters and readjusts well to different screen sizes. I'd also like to include a gallery that uses javascript as i haven't used any javascript on this site yet.
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.

      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="Curriculum Vitae">
      <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Curriculum Vitae</u> </h3>
      <p>
        Here i will have my twitter, instagram and facebook feed
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
        pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="Portfolio">
      <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Portfolio</u> </h3>
      <p>
        Here i will showcase some of my current projects and completed projects.
        <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
      </p>
    </div>


    <div class="content" id="Report">
      <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Report</u> </h3>
      <p>
        Here i will showcase some of my current projects and completed projects.
        <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat

    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

</body>

</html>
```

#### CSS:

```
#page {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 85%; 
    font-family: 'Arya', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#navbar {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;  
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 11%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    max-width: 85%;

}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
}
li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}

li:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 36px 40px; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    color: white; 
}

div.yt {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
} 

#twitter {}

.contentbox {
    font-family: 'Arya', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color:  grey;
}
.content {
    background-color: grey;
}
p {
    text-indent: 3%; 
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}
h3 {
    margin-left: 5px;
    max-width: 95%;
}
```

#### JS:

```
!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting my question correctly, are you able to help me out with my question?

Now the problem with my page is that even though the twitter feed and the youtube video are on the same line i am unable to alter the width of the twitter feed even though I have tried to in css. Also I want to know how to create some spacing between the video and the twitter feed, something like 2 or 3cm would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

As for putting the video and the twitter feed on the same line, switch your css to this:

```
#page {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 85%; 
    font-family: 'Arya', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#navbar {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;  
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 11%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    max-width: 85%;

}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
}
li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}

li:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 36px 40px; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    color: white; 
}

div.yt {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display:inline-block;
} 

#twitter {
  display:inline-block;
}

.contentbox {
    font-family: 'Arya', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color:  grey;
}
.content {
    background-color: grey;
}
p {
    text-indent: 3%; 
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}
h3 {
    margin-left: 5px;
    max-width: 95%;
}
```

The important part is the youtube div and the twitter div are both now using the style 'display:inline-block'. You probably also want to adjust the height of your twitter feed to match the height of the youtube video. To add a different font to your page I'd recommend using https://www.google.com/fonts. Pick a font you like, add it to your collection, click use at the bottom right and then copy the code.

Comment: I changed the css to what you told me to and it worked but when i tried changing the height and width of the twitter feed the width just stops getting bigger at a certain point. below ive included the code i used to resize it.                                                  

<div class="yt">
      <iframe height="500" width="650" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nKIu9yen5nc">
      </iframe>
    </div>

  <div id = "twitter">
    <a class="twitter-timeline"  height="500" width="600" href="https://twitter.com/applenws" data-widget-id="674678491141570560">Tweets by @applenws</a>
  </div>

Comment: You can't change the width in the link tag. You should change it in the twitter css style you already have. Just add whatever width you want there.

ex. 
#twitter {
  display:inline-block;
  width:600px;
}

Please mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem.